# how to get the file and folder information in java?

Tags: java, file

I'm doing a project that has a module as "File or folder information". It means, I need all open files and open directory details.

E.g.:

> If one file "aa.txt" was open by user, and the file is in "bb directory"; the output should be like
>
> ```
> aa.txt that file be in open
> bb dir be in open
> ```

and also, if you change that file, the message appear by that module as `aa.txt that file has been modified by this user.`

Comment: Is it like [Java File Watcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)?

Comment: yes .,It is lik file watcher in java.....

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that in pure java, you'll need to use a custom library (depending on the OS) as file/user/permissions information is hidden form Java to make it portable. You can only check if you can read or write to a file using standard java (you have few more methods as isDirectory, but not much more).

Comment: Based on iterating the files several times, their attributes can be compared against a hash to detect changes.

Comment: IO Notification? http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: That's true, but you won't know which user did the change nor if the file is currently open by a user.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at Java's **[java.io.File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)** API. You will get most of the things there.
For checking if the file has been modified, you can use `lastModified()` method.

**JDK 7** is giving a new `The WatchService API and File Change Notification API`. You can read about it **[here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/#6)**.