# How to get contents of a folder and put into an ArrayList

Tags: java, file

I want to use

```
File f = new File("C:\\");
```

to make an ArrayList with the contents of the folder.

I am not very good with buffered readers, so please tell me if that is better.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class buffered_read {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("C:\\");
    int x = 0;
    boolean b = true;
    File list[];
    while(b = true){

    }
}
}
```

Thanks,
obiedog

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the file and folder information in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026954/how-to-get-the-file-and-folder-information-in-java)

Comment: Sounds a bit like homework... Try using File.list().

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The easiest way of doing that is:

```
File f = new File("C:\\");
ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(f.listFiles()));
```

And if what you want is a list of names:

```
File f = new File("C:\\");
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(f.list()));
```

Comment: Does the File API automatically recurse into child folders?

Comment: @blong No, it doesn't. `File.listFiles()` only lists the content of the given directory. For recursive listing see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14676464/1340631 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/2534643/1340631.

Comment: Strange, `Paths.get(p.getParent()).listFiles()` and  `File parentFile = p.toFile().getParentFile().listFiles()` both return null.

Answer (score 30):

Have you [read the API documentation for `java.io.File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)?

```
File f = new File("C:\\");
File[] list = f.listFiles();
```

Comment: Reup for you. Good answer.

Answer (score 4):

The [`File`-class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) offers a [`listFiles()`-method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) which returns a `File`-array of all files in the current folder.

To make an ArrayList of them, you can use the [`Arrays`-class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) and it's [`asList()`-method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t-in-java).

If you only need the file-names or paths as Strings, there is also a [`list()`-method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) which returns a String-array. To convert the array to an ArrayList, follow the steps illustrated in the linked question.

Answer (score 3):

Streams are fast and very easy to read:

```
final Path rootPath = Paths.get("/tmp");

// All entries Path objects
ArrayList<Path> all = Files
        .list(rootPath)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

// Only regular files at Path objects
ArrayList<Path> regularFilePaths = Files
        .list(rootPath)
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

// Only regular files as String paths
ArrayList<String> regularPathsAsString = Files
        .list(rootPath)
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .map(Path::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve all the files recursively, you can do something like below

```
public class FileLister {

    static List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("C:\\tmp");
        listDirectory(file);
        System.out.println(fileList);
    }

    public static void listDirectory(File file) {
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            for(File currFile : files) {
                listDirectory(currFile);
            }
        }
        else {
            fileList.add(file.getPath());
        }
    }
}
```