# list all files in the folder and also sub folders

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List all files from a directory recursively with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534632/list-all-files-from-a-directory-recursively-with-java)

How can i return a file array that include all files on the folder and also sub folders my method just work for folder and it doesn't include sub folders .

```
public File[] listf(String directoryName) {

    // .............list file
    File directory = new File(directoryName);

    // get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listf(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(fList);
    return fList;
}
```

Comment: You can use `FileUtils`

Comment: Remove the block that checks if it is a sub directory?

Comment: FileUtils.listFiles(dir, new String[]{".xml"}, true)... in apache-commons

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Using you current code, make this tweak:

```
public void listf(String directoryName, List<File> files) {
    File directory = new File(directoryName);

    // Get all files from a directory.
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    if(fList != null)
        for (File file : fList) {      
            if (file.isFile()) {
                files.add(file);
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                listf(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: fyi if you want the current folder you can use `new File(".");'

Comment: Maybe public void listf(String directoryName, List<File> files) { is better

Comment: There should be null check for `fList` array before Iterating.

Comment: `if(fList != null{` is missing a `)`, just fix to `if(fList != null) {`

Answer (score 38):

Use [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter)) from Apache commons.

```
listFiles

public static Collection<File> listFiles(File directory,
                                         String[] extensions,
                                         boolean recursive)
Finds files within a given directory (and optionally its subdirectories) which match an array of extensions.
Parameters:
directory - the directory to search in
extensions - an array of extensions, ex. {"java","xml"}. If this parameter is null, all files are returned.
recursive - if true all subdirectories are searched as well
Returns:
an collection of java.io.File with the matching files
```

Answer (score 22):

You can return a `List` instead of an array and things gets much simpler.

```
    public static List<File> listf(String directoryName) {
        File directory = new File(directoryName);

        List<File> resultList = new ArrayList<File>();

        // get all the files from a directory
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        resultList.addAll(Arrays.asList(fList));
        for (File file : fList) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                resultList.addAll(listf(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(fList);
        return resultList;
    }
```

Comment: but i want to merge the array

Comment: Why? I mean: what is your problem and why would you want to avoid using lists which are doing all the merging for you?

Comment: yes excuse me i sleepy(sleeplessness) at the moment

Comment: this works , i have used it in my app

Comment: This is okay to recursively return files and directories within that specified directory. And as the question (even though its a duplicate) is asking how to return (only) files from the provided directory and files within all sub-directories you may have to change the codes a little bit:
//resultList.addAll(Arrays.asList(fList));
        for (File file : fList) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                resultList.add(file);
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                resultList.addAll(listf(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
        }