# Writing to a file in a recursive method

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to put all the Strings in my print statement below into a file.

I have a recursive method to check all directories, and sub-directories (which I think it was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676407/list-all-files-in-the-folder-and-also-sub-folders) I took code from).

Then it basically checks if the directory is empty, and if so, print the directory name:

```
File directory = new File(directoryName);
List<File> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
resultList.addAll(Arrays.asList(fList));
for (File file : fList) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        if (file.list().length == 0) {
            System.out.println(file.toString());
        }
        resultList.addAll(listf(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    }
}
return resultList;
```

Obviously, `resultList` is every directory so that's no good.

So I tried to replace the `System.out...` into a file with `PrintWriter`* (`writer.println(file.toString());`) but it left an empty output file.

I thought this was because I didn't initially close the `writer` but it seemed to not matter where I did this, because of the recursion. I tried instead to append to a `StringBuilder` (+ a new line) and then add that in one go to a file but that again just left a blank file.

So basically, my question is: How can I add each entry in the nested `if` into a text file (i.e. the output of `System.out.println(file.toString());`)

<sub>I initially had initialised the `PrintWriter` in the recursive method so ended up creating a file in every directory and every subdirectory - oops!</sub>

Comment: "`resultList` is every directory so that's no good." - does it have to be? Why don't you just collect empty directories?

Comment: The question you referenced is four years old. Do yourself a favor and use a file visitor: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

Comment: "I tried instead to append to a StringBuilder (+ a new line) and then add that in one go to a file but that again just left a blank file." - did you check the contents of that StringBuilder? If it wasn't empty your problem isn't recursion but how you write to the file - which you didn't show.

Comment: Yes - I guess collecting and returning empty directories would work - I'll give it a go later on when I get chance. True - I thought it was an old version as it was on my machine for a while so I just amended it slightly for my purpose; I'll have a look at up-to-date software. And, no the StringBuilder was not empty with a print statement, but the file contents were. Thanks all anyway; I might try a new solution with file visitor as mentioned above and see how I fare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It left a blank file.

To avoid that, you can enable the auto flush by using this overloaded constructor :

```
public PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)
```

Or you can also flush the writer before the program is terminated.

Note that `java.io.file.File` is an old API to manipulate files.
You should use `java.io` API that provides more reliable, simple and efficient way to manipulate files.
@crizzis refers it in its comment and he/she is right.
But you don't really need to create an `FileVisitor` implementation for such a simple case.

Here is an example relying on `Path` and `Files.walk()` .
The processing is performed by two Stream functions :

- filter empty directory (intermediary operation)
- for each : print the directory path in the writer (terminal operation)

Here is a full executable code (exception cases are not exhaustively handled. You have to do it in a more complete way according to your requirements):

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class WriterForEmptyDirectory {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("result")), true)) {

            String directoryPath = "a-path-to-analyse";
            Files.walk(Paths.get(directoryPath))
                 .filter(f -> {
                     try {
                         return Files.isDirectory(f) && Files.list(f)
                                                             .count() == 0;
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                         System.err.println("Error to handle for file " + f);
                         e.printStackTrace();
                         return false;
                     }
                 })
                 .forEach(f -> {
                     try {
                         writer.println(f);
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                         System.err.println("Error to handle for file " + f);
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                 });
        }
    }
}
```