# Adding characters to multiple filenames in Java

Tags: java, renaming

I currently have a big folder full of filenames in the format:

```
EXA_0100_01012014.csv
EXA_0114_11012014.csv
```

Always the same 3 letters at the start. I need to change all of these filenames so that they are in the format:

```
EXA_B_0100_01012014
```

So it's just a case of inserting an _B (always _B) after the first three letters. I'm only just started learning Java so my attempts so far are fairly limited:

```
File oldfile = new File("EXA_0100_01012014.csv");
File newfile = new File("EXA_B_0100_01012014.csv");
```

I just need to do this for a large number of files all with the same 3 letter prefix. All the numbers change from file to file though.

If someone could give me a nudge in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: couldn't shell script be a better tool to solve this problem? :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `substring`.

```
String fileName = "EXA_0100_01012014";
String newFileName = fileName.substring(0, 3) + "_B_" + fileName.substring(4);
```

Returns `newFileName` as:

```
EXA_B_0100_01012014
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
String newFilename = oldfile.getFileName().replace("EXA_", "EXA_B_");
oldfile.renameTo(new File(newFilename));
```

If you don't like the `replace()` approach you could use the `substring()` method instead.

```
String oldFilename = oldfile.getFileName();
String newFilename = oldFilename.substring(0, 3) + "_B_" + oldFilename.substring(4);
oldfile.renameTo(new File(newFilename));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the results from a quick google bomb: 
[First start looking at the renaming a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/renaming-a-file-using-java), Then you can instert a string by breaking the substrings apart and the prepending the first 3 characters and appending the rest after "_B". Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/renaming-a-file-using-java).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] h) {

    final File folder = new File("/home/you/Desktop");
    renameFilesForFolder(folder);

}

public static void renameFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            renameFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            if (fileEntry.getName().startsWith("EXA")) {
                fileEntry.renameTo(new File(fileEntry.getName().replaceAll("(EXA)(_)", "$1_B$2")));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.

I used the following links to help me:

1. Nagesh Chauhan's solution for file renaming
   http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/08/create-delete-rename-file-in-java.html
2. Philip Reichart's solution on file list
   [How to get contents of a folder and put into an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301764/how-to-get-contents-of-a-folder-and-put-into-arrary-list)

   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;

   public class RenameFiles 
   {

   ```
   public RenameFiles()
   {
       File f = new File ("C:/work/play/java/list");
       File[] list = f.listFiles();

       for (int inum = 0; inum < list.length; inum++)
       {
           File curf = list[inum];
           RenameFile(curf);
       }
   }

   public void RenameFile(File curf) 
   {
       String strfilename = curf.getAbsolutePath();
       StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(strfilename);
       int index = buf.indexOf("EXA_");
       buf.insert(index+4, "B_");

       String strnewfilename = buf.toString();
       strnewfilename = strnewfilename.replace('\\', '/');
       System.out.println(strnewfilename);

       File newFileName = new File(strnewfilename);

       try {  
           if (curf.renameTo(newFileName)) {  
               System.out.println("File "+strfilename+"renamed to "+strnewfilename+" successful !");  
           } else {  
               System.out.println("File "+strfilename+"renamed to "+strnewfilename+" failed !");  
           }  

       } catch (Exception e) {  
           e.printStackTrace();  
       }  
    }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       RenameFiles fobj = new RenameFiles();               
   }
   ```

   }