# How do I feed a static String with the files inside a folder with Java?

Tags: java

I'm new here so let me know if I'm going against any rules with this question.

I have a Java app that's doing what's needed: it gets N .txt files, creates 1 thread per file, and then creates an inverted index out of all these files, outputting the result into a single .txt file.

The output is how it's supposed to be, the thread management is working just fine, but there's still something I want to improve. This is how I'm grabbing the source files:

```
static String Docs [] = {"path/to/file1.txt", "path/to/file2.txt"}
```

But I wanted to do it automatically instead of having to list all files one by one. Imagine I have like 20,000 files, it would take a lot of time to do so.

I didn't find anything related to it and my professor says it's alright the way it is, but I wanted to know how to simply feed this variable with the files inside X path instead of having to list all files.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301764/how-to-get-contents-of-a-folder-and-put-into-an-arraylist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get contents of a folder and put into an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301764/how-to-get-contents-of-a-folder-and-put-into-an-arraylist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to scan a local folder and populate the file paths in the `Docs` array.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class GetFilesFromDirectory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String folderPath = "/Users/js/test";
        int depth = 1;

        List<String> DocsList = getFiles(folderPath, depth);
        String[] Docs = new String[DocsList.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < DocsList.size(); i++) {
            Docs[i] = DocsList.get(i);
        }

        //for check
        for (String Doc : Docs) {
            System.out.println(Doc);
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getFiles(String pathToSearch, int depth) {
        List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Stream<Path> paths = Files.find(Paths.get(pathToSearch), depth, (path, attributes) -> attributes.isRegularFile());
            paths.forEach(path -> files.add(path.toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return files;
    }
}
```

**Test run:**

**Say the local disk has a folder with some files in it.**

```
$ ls -l /Users/js/test
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

**Running the code with `folderPath = /Users/js/test`, and `depth = 1` will give:**

```
/Users/js/test/file1.txt
/Users/js/test/file2.txt
/Users/js/test/file3.txt
```